# Progress 4GL - how to remove a line break from a string?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Can anyone help me on removing line break from a string? During csv file export it is creating 2 rows in a single cell. Kindly throw a lamp in the dark

```
 lvc_string = "|
               5678".
```

after removing the line break it should be

```
 lvc_string = "|5678".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Mike's answer you can also use the tilde [~ special character](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920643769.html) to indicate linefeed and carriage return characters:

```
lvc_string = replace( replace( lvc_string, '~n', '' ), '~r', '' ).
```

Answer (score 5):

```
lvc_string = REPLACE(REPLACE(lvc_string, CHR(10), ""), CHR(13), "")
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike Fechner. It worked!!
CHR(10) and CHR(13) Means?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: That's ASCII codes for CR and NL

Comment: But then the other way round. :-)

Comment: How is that minor detail relevant here ;)